# Confusion Matrix - TP when both true/predicted columns have a value

Tags: python-3.x, confusion-matrix

I need to create a confusion matrix as follows:

```
Truth - any value & Predicted - any value : True Positive
Truth - NaN       & Predicted - NaN       : True Negative
Truth - any value & Predicted - NaN       : False Negative
Truth - NaN       & Predicted - any value : False Positive
```

This is different from the typical confusion matrix calculation, as I do not have labels to compare. Is there an easy way to do this in Python (even if it means calculating the TP/TN/FP/FN values manually)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you define your labels to be:

- True: "my number is not NaN"
- False: "my number is NaN"

Then your setting turns out to be a simple binary classification task, and you can use the confusion matrix without problem.

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

pred  = [np.nan,    234,  1, 0, np.nan, -23,    3.2]
truth = [np.nan, np.nan, 21, 1,      0,  21, np.nan]

# Convert your predictions and true values into labels
pred_labels = ~np.isnan(pred)  
truth_labels = ~np.isnan(truth)

print(pred_labels)
# [False  True  True  True False  True  True]

print(truth_labels)
# [False False  True  True  True  True False]

print(confusion_matrix(pred_labels, truth_labels))
# [[1 1]
#  [2 3]]
```

And if you want to check TP, TN, FP, FN:

```
(tn, fp, fn, tp) = confusion_matrix(pred_labels, truth_labels).ravel()
print(tp)  # 3
print(tn)  # 1
print(fp)  # 1
print(fn)  # 2
```

NB: you can also use `~np.isfinite(x)` instead of `np.isna(x)` should you want to avoid infinity values (`np.inf`) aswell.

Comment: I really appreciate it! This works great when I have numerical values, but these can also be strings or dates (so I would check for empty vs non-empty values). I am currently working on that scenario. Thank you!

Comment: I have noticed that, when all values are True (for both my predicted and truth labels), the confusion matrix .ravel() function only returns one number [[x]], where x is the total number of experiment (which in this case are all true positives). Is this expected?

Comment: If prediction and truth are equal, I can find the same behavior as you indeed. Weird that it does not also output tn, fp, fn = 0.

Comment: @Irina I understood what happened. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248401/why-is-my-confusion-matrix-returning-only-one-number/65248402#65248402