# Why is my confusion matrix returning only one number?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm doing a binary classification. Whenever my prediction equals the ground truth, I find `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` to return a single value. Isn't there a problem?

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix([True, True], [True, True])
# [[2]]
```

I would expect something like:

```
[[2 0]
 [0 0]]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should fill-in `labels=[True, False]`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true=[True, True], y_pred=[True, True], labels=[True, False])
print(cm)

# [[2 0]
#  [0 0]]
```

### Why?

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), the output of `confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)` is:

> C: ndarray of shape (n_classes, n_classes)

The variable `n_classes` is either:

- guessed as the number of unique values in `y_true` or `y_pred`
- taken from the length of optional parameters `labels`

In your case, because you did not fill in `labels`, the variable `n_classes` is guessed from the number of unique values in `[True, True]` which is 1. Hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 1 number because you didn't specify your labels. I think this code will help you out to get true_positives, true negative, precesion, recall, f1-score etc

**Code**

```
from sklearn import metrics

A     = [True, True]
B     = [True, True]
label = [True, False] 


# True positives and False Negatives
cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true=A, y_pred=B, labels=label)
print(cm)

# Report (f1-score, precesion, recall, support)
report = metrics.classification_report([True, False], [False, True], digits=3,output_dict=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(report).transpose()
df
```

**Results**

```
[[2 0]
 [0 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a clear duplicate of my answer posted earlier, where I apparently also got a downvote. Unfair as possible?

Comment: Yaa! I took your answer and modify it for more information

Comment: But what you added is not what the question asks for.